# How can i render page without loading layout page in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, layout, asp.net-mvc-5

In mvc project,recently I am working on project's performance improvement.I am facing problem for loading layout page.when I am rendering or changing page it should load only content on page,not the layout page.so, I want solution to render my content pages without loading of Layout page.

Comment: try to be more verbose, add some code and stuff...

Comment: I believe you are looking to load dynamic data without page refresh? am i correct. If so you need to show some sort of view code if you are looking for examples or help.

Comment: yes, I want to load page data dynamically. But that time i don't want to refresh or load layout page, only body should render.I am having two pages and when i switch from one page to another then the layout page data should not be load, only another page data should load.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Layout` property of the content pages/views as `null` on which you don't want the layout page to be loaded.

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Comment: Actually, I want layout on every page, but I don't want to render the layout page every time. By means that, I only want to load render body rather than whole page.

Comment: Setting the `Layout` property `null` will only load the content body without the Layout.

Comment: But,I want that layout. If I will null the layout then page without layout render that i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use either ajax and partial views or any other javascript UI frameworks like [knockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Knockout, Knockout & jQuery can provide you with the postback you are looking for. Here is a link.

http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Please elaborate it. From my understanding, you wanted a very basic layout for better performance.

This you can achieve by creating a new layout page and remove all the scripts and css files from it. Then use this layout page as your layout for the pages.

Your layout can be very minimal, something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's assume, I have two page A and B. Now, I want same layout on both pages. But, what i want is, When I redirect A to B, I want to refresh only renderbody part. Currently when I redirect from A to B, whole page is loading that I don't want. I hope you understand my problem.